# IE10, 11 CDATA with hyphens parsed wrong

Tags: javascript, html, xml, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I experienced such problem: when trying to parse xml that I receive from server, messages contained in CDATA blocks are parsed in IE10, 11 till first hyphens found.

See example of XML that I received:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<response>
    <task>results</task>
    <finish_msg><![CDATA[
      <div class="jq_results_container_outer">
        <div class="jq-msg-alert-0">
        </div>
      </div><br />]]>
   </finish_msg>
</response>
```

And when I called such Javascript code in IE 10, 11 `var data = response.getElementsByTagName('finish_msg')[0].firstChild.data`
I get `data` equals to `<div class="jq_results_container_outer"><div class="jq`

Everything works for FF, Chrome, Opera, IE 8, 9.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this bug submission to IE11:

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1398926/ie11-does-not-parse-cdata-containing-hyphens-correctly

It appears the bug is fixed in Edge and IE11 (11.0.10240.16431), but for me I still get the bug on IE11.

The bug can be summarized:

```
new DOMParser().parseFromString('<tag><![CDATA[data-with-hyphen]]></tag>', 'text/xml').firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

The result will have a truncated value located at the first occurrence of a hyphen.

Edit: As a workaround, you can retrieve the contents using this format:

```
response.getElementsByTagName('finish_msg')[0].textContent
```

Comment: But the bug is marked unreproducible - did you find a server side solution - without modifying the javascript?

Comment: I did not. My solution was to modify javascript.

Comment: Replacing `.firstChild.nodeValue` with `.textContent` in my JavaScript to retrieve HTML inside XML retrieved via Ajax worked for me.  Thank you.