# Internet Explorer XML Parsing wrong at hypens and can't make repro example

Tags: javascript, xml, debugging, internet-explorer-11

I am debugging the following code of a bigger system which is not written by me. There is XML coming from a server via AJAX which is not parsed properly. The following explains the problem.

Note the hyphens - internet explorer is inserting them if there is one in a CDATA part.

[image]

When I print for example

```
console.log(a.item(4).childNodes.item(0));
```

I get

```
`{"INCD":"30362790021","sycd":"BKJ2`
```

To debug the problem, I try to create a minimal example.

I have copied the variable `source` (by setting a breakpoint with the condition .ocmmand == 'List_detail') to a simple HTML Javascript file as follows:

```
<script>

    var source = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE primrose SYSTEM \"dtd/primrose.dtd\">\n<primrose><array type=\"string\"> .... </primrose>";

    var xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(source, 'text/xml');
    var a = xml.documentElement.childNodes;
    console.log(a);
    console.log(a.item(4).childNodes.item(0));
</script>
```

The example in full length is at http://pastebin.com/GaHdjiWW

But this seems to work just fine:

[image]

When I run `console.log(a.item(4).childNodes.item(0));` I get

`{"INCD":"30362790021","sycd":"BKJ2-2","type_code":"00000050555","type_name":"BKJ","series_code":"110302280810","web_product_id":"10302280810","series_name":"Cross Recessed Pan Head Screws","disp_brandName":"MISUMI","brd_code":"MSM1","ecal_brd_code":"MSM","main_photo":"MSM1/PHOTO/10302280810.jpg","catch_copy":null,"cad_2d":"1","cad_2d_type":"1","cad_3d":"1","cad_3d_type":"2","scene7_img_product":[{"img_fileName":"110302280810_20149999_m_01_99999_jp","img_description":""}],"ary_displayLink":null,"ary_param_verify":"BKJ{2}\t{2}","ary_param_disp":"BKJ{2}\t{2}","param_conv_bef":null,"param_conv_bef_disp":null,"canOrder":"1"}`

and so on...

Internet Explorer Version is 11.0.9600.18314

I do know [IE10, 11 CDATA with hyphens parsed wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039982/ie10-11-cdata-with-hyphens-parsed-wrong) and it somehow seems to be a bug in IE. But why can I not reproduce it in the same browser?

Comment: Maybe there is some strange utf-8 character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I traced it down to using MutationObserver.observe with childList and subtree options: https://github.com/talee/mutationobserver-breaks-characterdata. **Workaround: Use deprecated MutationEvents in IE < Edge**. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mutationobserver-polyfill does the job for IE 11.

Breaking code:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {});
// Other mutation types/combos work fine
observer.observe(document, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});
```

Test:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var expectedContent = 'hello-world';
// <div>hello-world</div> breaks too. Using CDATA as that's my current use
// case.
var xml = parser.parseFromString('<div><![CDATA[' + expectedContent + ']]></div>','text/xml');
var result = xml.firstChild.firstChild.data;

// Output test results for viewing
if (result != expectedContent) {
  statusOut.textContent = 'FAIL';
} else {
  statusOut.textContent = 'SUCCESS';
}
resultOut.textContent = 'Result: "' + result + '"';
```

I created a bug for IE 11 on https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8589859/.

However based on https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1398926/ie11-does-not-parse-cdata-containing-hyphens-correctly, it's unlikely the issue will be fixed as it's not security related:

> Posted by Brad [MSFT] on 2/17/2016 at 12:02 PM
>
> I see. Thank you for
>   the repro. I am able to repro using IE 11.29.10586.0 Unfortunately we
>   are no longer working IE bugs unless they are security related. Sorry
>   to be the bearer of bad news. I will leave the feedback in its current
>   state since it does not apply to Edge.

Comment: Awesome you reproduced this!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was somehow caused by the iframe resizing script:

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/issues/372