# responseXML object of XMLHttpRequest has incomplete data when special characters are present [IE11]

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, utf-8, xmlhttprequest

**Situation:** I am sending a POST request using the `XMLHttpRequest` Object.

My request header is as follows :

`X-Requested-With - XMLHttpRequest`

`Content-Type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

My reponse headers are :

`Content-Type   text/xml; charset=utf-8`

`Transfer-Encoding  chunked`

My response body is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<json>
<![CDATA[ {"prop1":"value1","prop2":{"prop21","value2-1"}}]]>
</json>
</response>
```

in my callback function i try to create JSON object out of the response, i achieve that in the following manner :

```
var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("json")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
```

where xhr is the `XMLHttpRequest` object

**Problem :** This approach works fine in all browsers except IE11, in IE11 if the data sent by server contains characters like `-` or `!` then responseXML is not completely formed,

for e.g in the response above the value of `prop21` is `value2-1`. In this scenario `responseXML` object created by IE11 contains data only till `value2`. All data after `value2` is absent in the object formed. Thus when `JSON.parse` is called it breaks because of incorrect syntax .

It's working in google chrome, firefox. This is specifically happening in IE11 can anyone tell me why `responseXML` object created by IE11 doesn't contain full data when characters like `-` or `!` are present ?

Comment: I did some searches, and this seems a bug of Microsoft Edge / IE11, what you could do, is, maybe, change the hyphen to another character

Comment: Can you provide the article link clearly stating this is a IE 11/edge bug

Comment: I saw here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/061721c1-68a5-4f38-83ec-d7e4b596cc1d/problem-parsing-xml-with-a-hyphen-in-ie11?forum=iewebdevelopment and saw some solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039982/ie10-11-cdata-with-hyphens-parsed-wrong

Comment: `var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("json"));` should not even work.... How do you parse a collection??